# How to import local git repository into svn?

Tags: git-svn

I am working on local git repository and I need to push my local git into *existing* svn repository. My git repository is pure local git repository, it was ***not*** init using `git svn clone`.

How can I import this local git repo into svn?

Preferably I'ld like to keep the git history being imported into SVN.

Currently the SVN repository is structure as:

```
https://svnrepohost
           /branches
           /tags
           /trunk
                  /projectA
                  /projectB
                  /newProject
```

What I need it is to import my git repository into the `https://svnrepohost/trunk/newProject` above, assuming the `newProject` folder is empty.

Comment: Does the remote Subversion repository already exist, or are you trying to create a new Subversion repository from your local Git repository?

Comment: The remote subversion repository already exist.

Comment: So how do you want it to go into the Subversion repository? A new branch? Overwriting the trunk? What about history: do you want the full history of the Git repo in the Subversion branch, or just how it looks at the moment?

Comment: It will be overwriting the trunk project. Preferably keeping the full history from Git. I updated the question to clarify the question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I have finally solved this problem by the following steps:

1. Setup appropriate project folder in svn to be imported to, for example `http://svnrepo/svn/trunk/newProject`
2. Create a new git-svn repository

   > git svn clone `http://svnrepo/svn/trunk/newProject`
3. Add the git repo that we want to import as ***remote*** to the *new* git-svn repo

   > git remote add origin ../original-git-repo
4. Pull all the data from original-git-repo

   > git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
5. Rebase local repository against svn

   > git svn rebase
6. Commit the changes into svn

   > git svn dcommit
7. Clean up the remote

   > git remote delete origin

Comment: Worked great though I think Step 7 should be git remote remove origin.

Comment: point 2 always creates a newProject folder in the path that I'm running `git svn`. in item 3 what do you mean by `../` is your git repository one folder up than your current path? did you `CD` to your svn repository before running item 3? and I'm getting error `Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history` on step 5

Comment: Worked greatly! However, I had to do `git pull --allow-unrelated-histories origin master` as step 4, otherwise git was refusing to merge unrelated histories. I had an initial commit in my SVN repository, maybe that was the reason.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to just `svn import` the Git directory. That will lose you your Git commit history, however.

First of all, make sure the `.git` directory won't be imported by setting the `global-ignores` in the Subversion config file. Open your `~/.subversion/config` file (that'll be in something like `C:\Users\username\.subversion\config` on Windows), find the section starting `[miscellany]`, and add a line directly underneath reading as below:

```
global-ignores = .git
```

(if you already have a line with `global-ignores =` that doesn't have a `#` in front of it, then just add `.git` to the end of that line.)

Next, run the below:

```
svn import <path-to-local-git-repository> https://svnrepohost/trunk/newProject
```

That should copy the contents of the local Git repository onto the server exactly where you want it.

Comment: I believe if this solution is going to loose all the commit history it is equal to downloading a local copy of git, copying those files into svn local copy and commit svn. I also like to keep the history of commit (changes to files in each version) which is very important

Answer (score 0):

You may use [SubGit](http://subgit.com).

```
$ svnadmin create repo.svn
$ subgit configure repo.svn                                                                                                                                                              

...                                                                                                                                                                           

            CONFIGURATION SUCCESSFUL                                                                                                                                                                                   

            Adjust '/tmp/repo.svn/conf/subgit.conf' file                                                                                                                                                               
            and then run                                                                                                                                                                                               
                subgit install "repo.svn"                                                                                                                                                                              
            to complete SubGit installation.
$ nano repo.svn/conf/subgit.conf #edit to set git.default.repository=path/to/your/bare/git/repository
$ subgit install repo.svn
```

I would also recommend you to create a bare clone of your Git repository and to specify path to it (in git.default.repository) instead of your original repository. I.e.

```
$ git clone --bare path/to/your/original/repository path/to/your/bare/git/repository
```

After "subgit install" command the repositories (repo.svn and repo.git) will be in continuos synchronization (triggered by pre-receive hook in Git [that starts on pushing to your bare repository] and pre-commit in SVN). To stop synchronization you may run

```
$ subgit uninstall repo.svn
```

Comment: I took a quick look at the subgit website, do you know how to use subgit with existing svn repository and assuming that we don't have admin access to the svn repository?

Comment: One has to have admin access to svn or git repository in order to install SubGit into it.

Answer (score 0):

- git svn clone http://svnrepo/svn/trunk/newProject
- git remote add origin ../original-git-repo
- git fetch origin
- git checkout -b lmaster remotes/origin/master
- git rebase master
- git svn rebase
- git svn dcommit